# Stylelint failing silently as npm script

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, npm-scripts, stylelint

I'm setting up stylelint for a project, everything works as expected when run from the cli:

```
$ stylelint 'css/**/*.css' --fix

css/style.css
 20:18  ×  Expected newline after ":" with a multi-line declaration declaration-colon-newline-after
...
...
```

However, when run as an `npm script` no output appears (beyond logging the command) and the errors seem to be ignored:

```
$ npm run stylelint

> project lint:css path/project
> stylelint 'css/**/*.css' --fix
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "stylelint": "stylelint 'css/**/*.css' --fix"
  },
```

Any idea how to get the console output AND exit on errors when stylelint is run as an npm script?

Comment: It actually seems `> stylelint 'css/**/*.css' --fix` doesnt run at all via `npm` regardless of the fact it logs out to the console

Comment: The issue is with the globstar pattern, as `"stylelint": "stylelint 'css/file.css' --fix"` runs as expected via npm

Answer (score 9):

The issue turned out to be the quotes around the globstar pattern. Most other scripts allow you to wrap the globstar in single quotes `'`, however stylelint seems to require escaped double quotes:

`"stylelint": "stylelint \"src/**/*.css\" --fix"`

Comment: You're my hero, Vinnie

Comment: Not all heros wear masks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like appending `; exit 0` also does the trick:

```
"stylelint": "stylelint 'css/**/*.css' --fix; exit 0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (which did not help in my case though). Could you please elaborate why this would help?